# unexpected result from fgets() no (f)scanf

Tags: c, fgets

I have looked at other similar problems with fgets on here and they all seem to be caused by an (f)scanf. The problem I am running into does not involve (f)scanf.

Here is the while loop I am using to read stdin line by line.

```
while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)!=NULL){
            char* newLine[6]; //the array of characters
            int i = 0; //counter

            char *next=strtok(line," ");
            while (i<6){
                newLine[i]=next;
                next=strtok(NULL," ");
                ++i;
            }
```

line is definitely big enough to hold the input. I know exactly how many words there will be that is why I use 6. The 2nd while loop removes the spaces and puts the results into newLine to be evaluated. This works for all lines except for the very first one. this is the output.

```
A 344532111 S SPY 300 117.880000 //ignore input
A 344532111 S SPY 300 117.880000 //line 2
R 344532111 SPY 300 117.840000   //line 3
T 344532111 SPY 100              //line 4
C 344532111 SPY 100              //line 5
A 344533172 B SPY 200 117.110000 //line 6
A 344533348 B SPY 280 118.050000 //line 7       
X 344533348 SPY                  //line 8
344532111 S 100 117.840000 //results
344533172 B 200 117.110000 //results
```

There should be a result for each line that starts with A.
I know the the first line is not read because if I have it output the first character that it finds in each line, it only shows one 'A'
Additionally, the lines will throw an error as if it weren't there. (each line works like a command that initiates different functions based on the line before it. It wouldn't throw an error if it read the first line. That is why the first two lines are duplicates.)

The problem is that it skips the first line inputted into the terminal, but reads everything else after that as expected.

Does anyone have any idea as to what I may be doing incorrectly? Perhaps using `fgets()` wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide more code? It is hard to spot the problem with less information

Comment: Please post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You should show more code, as well as input and output.  How can we determine whether the problem is anywhere else?  I take it that `line` is declared as an array and is NOT a pointer.

Comment: It's risky, I don't want to put too much or my professor my consider it cheating. I'll update with some more info though...

Comment: If you think that your prof will identify you if you post more code, then *you* think you're cheating and should stop immediately.

Comment: why not put something not useful in first line of the file you are reading..

Comment: I don't think I'm cheating. I think my professor will identify me if I post more code because they could and I wouldn't put it past them to call it cheating. I don't trust my school in the slightest.
@optim because it's reading from stdin, not a specific file. It works fine if I use a specific file. it reads all the lines in that case.

Comment: Have you verified that your program is skipping the line by outputting it immediately after the `fgets`?  *ie* `printf("Read line: %s", line);`.  That will go a long way to determining whether there's a problem with your input or a problem with your processing.

Comment: The code you show is probably not the code causing the problem.  Reduce your code to the minimum that shows your problem, or (better) reduce it so it shows a variant of your problem (with 3 words per line instead of 6, for example).  But show code that is failing.  Your shown code doesn't skip the first line, for example. You should be checking the return from `strtok()`. I'm not convinced I'd use `strtok()` in the first place, but that's a separate discussion. Your code doesn't do anything special with lines that start with 'A'. Some of the lines do not have 6 words, but you still try for 6.

Comment: Are you typing all that stuff every time you run your program? I guess you are not. How do you feed the data to the standard input? Are you using a pipe or are you copy-pasting? On the other hand, is there any `gets()`, `fgets()` or `fflush()` before that code?

Comment: @paddy helped me see the problem more specifically, not that I know why it happens any more. The reason it is "ignoring" the first line is because it is not reading the first 'A' which is integral to the program deciphering what the line means.

Comment: @comocomocomocomo I have tried by hand, with clipboard and with files. It works flawlessly when using files.

Comment: Is `line` defined as an array or as a pointer?

Comment: @KeithThompson it is defined as an array. `char line[1024];`